# Stop TWTweetComposeViewController automatically cancelling when device is locked

Tags: objective-c, ios, twitter

I'm using the `TWTweetComposeViewController` within my application. If the user locks device (or switches apps) while the compose tweet dialog is active, then unlocks it, the compose tweet dialog will cancel automatically (`TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultCancelled` is the result of the views' completionHandler property).
Furthermore, this seems to be the standard behaviour as it also happens in Mobile Safari and Photos.

I would like to ask if there is a way to override this behaviour such that when I lock the app when the dialog is up and unlock it, the window will remain just as the user left it?

Finally, perhaps it's worth noting that I do call `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];` after the `TWTweetComposeViewController`'s completionHandler returns a result, changing this would interfere with the behaviour of tapping the cancel or done button from the `TWTweetComposeViewController`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the default behavior that can't be changed.

You may, however, try the following.

In viewWillDisappear(), if TWTweetComposeViewController is showing, save the text and in viewWillAppear(), show the TWTweetComposeViewController with the text again.